# laravel 4.1 unique validation on update fails

Tags: php, validation, laravel, laravel-4

Laravel 4.1. I want to update a city, check the rules and it fails on unique check.

Rules:

```
public static $rules = [
    'name' => 'required|alpha_dash|unique:cities',
    'slug' => 'alpha_dash|unique:cities',
    'seo_title' => 'required|max:60|unique:cities',
    'seo_description' => 'required|max:160|unique:cities',
    'rank' => 'integer',
    'visible' => 'integer'
];
```

I know, I can smth like:

```
'name' => 'required|alpha_dash|unique:cities, name, ##',
```

where ## - id, but I cant dynamically set id to updated one.

```
'name' => "required|alpha_dash|unique:cities, name, $id", // doesnt work
'name' => "required|alpha_dash|unique:cities, name, $this->id", // doesnt work
```

Is there any way to do it normally ?

Comment: The query generated with this is "WHERE <>"... @mozg

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in separate ways.

An easy way is to use different rules based on different actions . When you will create the model, you will use the rules that you currently have.

When you will update the model, you will change the `unique:cities` to `exists:cities`

I usually do this with a validation service.

You create a base abstract Validator in services/ , which has a passes() function.

For each model, you create a ModelValidator , in your case CityValidator. Where you put your rules like :

```
public static $rules = [
    'new'=>[
    'name' => 'required|alpha_dash|unique:cities',
    'slug' => 'alpha_dash|unique:cities',
    'seo_title' => 'required|max:60|unique:cities',
    'seo_description' => 'required|max:160|unique:cities',
    'rank' => 'integer',
    'visible' => 'integer'],

    'edit'=>[
    'name' => 'required|alpha_dash|exists:cities',
    'slug' => 'alpha_dash|unique:cities',
    'seo_title' => 'required|max:60|exists:cities',
    'seo_description' => 'required|max:160|exists:cities',
    'rank' => 'integer',
    'visible' => 'integer'
    ]
];
```

Comment: yeah, i know that way, but maybe there is a way to pass id there ? in my example, 4 duplicate rules are not really cool

Comment: your way is too complicated, there is an ID in unique rule for that purpose but there is no nice way to pass there id

Comment: Please check this : https://github.com/bradleySuira/laravel-context-validator/blob/master/examples/unique-on-update.php

Comment: yeah, saw this solution, didnt like it, thought of smth more beautiful. its a shame, there is no built in solution to pass that id. dont know why it is not improved. thanks anyway

Comment: btw exists doesnt check if the value in the field is duplicated

Answer (score 0):

The 3rd argument accepts a value to be ignored... If you want to do a `WHERE` clause, do it like:

```
'name' => array("required", "alpha_dash", "unique:cities,name,null,id,id,$this->id"...
```

The docs says:

> **Adding Additional Where Clauses**
>
> You may also specify more conditions that will be added as "where"
>   clauses to the query:

```
'email' => 'unique:users,email_address,NULL,id,account_id,1'
```

> In the rule above, only rows with an account_id of 1 would be included in the unique check.

Learn by example:

```
email => unique:users,email_address,id,NULL,field_1,value_1,field_2,value_2,field_x,value_x
```

Generates the query:

```
SELECT
    count(*) AS AGGREGATE
FROM
    `entries`
WHERE
    `email_address` = ?
AND `id` <> NULL
AND `field_1` = `value_1`
AND `field_2` = `value_2`
AND `field_x` = `value_x`
```

Comment: **The 3rd argument is not a value - it is ID to be ignored.** No need to pass where. To update 14 row i simply have to pass 14 as 3rd argument: unique:cities, name, 14. But i cant pass dynamically id. $this->id doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

I found an elegant-ish way to do this using [`fadion/ValidatorAssistant`](https://github.com/fadion/ValidatorAssistant):

```
<?php

use Fadion\ValidatorAssistant\ValidatorAssistant;

class CityValidator extends ValidatorAssistant {

    // standard rules
    public static $rules = [
        'name' => 'required|alpha_dash',
        'slug' => 'alpha_dash',
        'seo_title' => 'required|max:60',
        'seo_description' => 'required|max:160',
    ];

    // some preparation before validation
    protected function before()
    {
        // Inject the given city id into the unique rules
        $this->rules['name'] .= 'unique:cities,name,' . $this->inputs['id'];
        $this->rules['slug'] .= 'unique:cities,slug,' . $this->inputs['id'];
        $this->rules['seo_title'] .= 'unique:cities,seo_title,' . $this->inputs['id'];
        $this->rules['seo_description'] .= 'unique:cities,seo_description,' . $this->inputs['id'];
    }
```

There's almost certainly a more elegant way to do this when you need several fields to be unique database-wide, but the above works very well for times when you only need one part to be unique.

Comment: i am using a function, which i pass to validator, e.g. `Model::rules($id);`. The function checks for unique rules and concatenates the specified id. Dead simple & effective.